# want to prevent permission group from seeing sprint capacity in Azure Boards

Tags: azure-devops, azure-boards

I have a permission group in Azure DevOps that I want to limit their access in Azure Boards. I want to give the members of this group the ability to create and update work items in my default team's sprint but I don't want this group to be able to see the team's sprint capacity.

The capacity I'm referring to is when you go to an Azure DevOps project -> Boards -> Sprints -> Capacity tab.

I've looked through the Permissions page in my project settings and can't find anything regarding capacity.

Is there a way to give access to the work items in a sprint but prevent access to that sprint's capacity page? Is it even possible?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According to your description, I tested setting the Iterations permission and did some research and found that there is currently no option to grant access to the work items in a sprint but prevent access to that sprint's capacity page.

You could use "Request a feature" on the left side of [Developer Community](https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/report?space=21&entry=suggestion) to open a new suggestion ticket.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I think the workaround would be to create a new team and add this particular permission group.